# Pandas: how to add an incremental value to a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I want to add a column id, for the first row I would like to start with a precise value (for example start_id = 1200) and for each row add 1 to the value of the previous id.

dataframe:

```
    x   
1   paris   
2   paris  
3   lyon  
4   lyon   
5   toulouse
```

Expected output:

```
    id     x      
1   1200   paris   
2   1201   paris  
3   1202   lyon  
4   1203   lyon   
5   1204   toulouse
```

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
df.insert(start_id, 'id', range(start_id, 1 + len(df)))
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `insert`? The first param should be the location at which the column should be inserted. Your start_id should fulfill 0<=start_id<= no. of columns in your dataframe. Your value 1200 is too large for it

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it with `range()` and `len(df)`, So it will start from **1200** and add `row's` on id `column` incrementally

```
df['id'] = range(1200, 1200+len(df))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a different way:

```
df.assign(id=df.reset_index().index + 1200)
```

Output:

```
          x    id
1     paris  1200
2     paris  1201
3      lyon  1202
4      lyon  1203
5  toulouse  1204
```